# CloudTable.ExecuteQuery().ToList() is hanging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure cosmos DB table.

In the following code, call to result.ToList() hangs.

I have tried several options such as TCP and HTTP.

However, if I make MVC controller async and use async query then everything works.

But as this is an old application, I cannot change all controllers and corresponding calls to async

```
private static string GetFinalFilter(Guid section, string page, string property, string lang)
    {
        string partitionKeyFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, GetPartitionKey(page));
        string sectionFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForGuid("Section", QueryComparisons.Equal, section);
        string pageFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Page", QueryComparisons.Equal, page);
        string propertyFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Property", QueryComparisons.Equal, property);
        string languageFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Language", QueryComparisons.Equal, lang);

        string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionKeyFilter, TableOperators.And, sectionFilter), TableOperators.And,
           TableQuery.CombineFilters(pageFilter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.CombineFilters(propertyFilter, TableOperators.And, languageFilter)));

        return finalFilter;
    }

    private static string ProductIsNotDefinedSectionIsNotDefined(string page, string property, string lang, string defaultLang)
    {
        string finalFilter = GetFinalFilter(Guid.Empty, page, property, lang);

        TableQuery<MDEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<MDEntity>().Where(finalFilter);
        var result =  mdTable.ExecuteQuery<MDEntity>(tableQuery);
        var list = result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very dangerous to go from async -->Sync --> async and it will give you deadlocks. 
What you can do is on the async Executioncall to Cosmos write, .GetAwaiter().GetResult(), then you force it to actually return the result.